# What does protected[session] mean in Scala?

Tags: scala, protected

Wandering through [ScalaQuery](http://scalaquery.org/) source code I've found such declarations (many of the kind actually):

```
private[session] val dyn = new DynamicVariable[Session](null)
```

and

```
def forDataSource(ds: DataSource): Database = new Database {
  protected[session] def createConnection(): Connection = ds.getConnection
}
```

What does that `[session]` mean? And I thought a function defined inside a function can not be `protected`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

But `createConnection` is not inside `forDataSource`, it's inside `Database` -- see the `new Database {` on the previous line?

It means that everything in the scope `session` (which might be a class, object or package -- I don't know) can see that definition, plus the classes that extend `Database`.

Comment: session in this case is package scope

Answer (score 0):

`private[<scope>]` modifier means "private for the *scope*", i.e. only classes that belong to the (package or class) *scope* have access to the member.

`protected[<scope>]` means that only classes that extend this class **and** belong to the *scope* have access to the member.

Beside those, there is also `private[this]`, which means that the member is visible only inside a concrete instance of the class.